# Bash Terminal colors for filetypes

Tags: bash

Bash terminal seems to not have colors for certain types of files, such as docx, pdf...

Is it possible to add colors for these in the output of `ls`, or no?

Comment: This isn't a `bash` feature, it's a feature of `ls`.

Comment: The color change for each file type is done using the file /etc/DIR_COLORS. Please check it